# How to hide a stream from particular users in RTC source control?

Tags: rtc

How can I hide particular streams from particular team members which are in same Project Area / Team ?

It seems the only way to achieve this is to change the visibility on the stream to a team area. This team area contains the users that I just want to be able to view the stream.

I'm using RTC version 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the owner of the Stream is usually the way I go about "hiding" a Stream.

Instead of putting the project area or a team as owner of the Stream, I put myself.
Putting, as you mention, a "Team Area of one" is another option.

This is part of the RTC3.0.1 release, which does have "[permissions to control access to streams](https://jazz.net/library/article/215#share_workspace)", and not only set the ownership on the stream, but also on the component, and restrict said component to the team owning the stream:

> Make the component private by selecting Flux Capacitor 2 and clicking on the Change Owner button.
>   In the ownership dialog, expand JUnit Project and select Flux Capacitor Tiger Team.
>   **Visibility is limited by checking the Restrict to members of this team area and its child team areas**, as shown in Figure 10

[image: restrict]